# Chrome workspaces not working with Source Maps and Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I've recently started working in a Browserify built Javascript app that uses source maps with ReactJs and I haven't been able to get Chrome's Workspace to work. I'm following the same steps I used in my previous AngularJs app that wasn't using source maps

1. Right click and add folder to workspace
2. Right click a javascrit file in the localhost directory and select "map to file system resource"
3. Select select the associated file in the workspace

After doing this I get the error below.

```
Source map http://localhost/B2BMessageRunner/WebApp/build/scripts/bundle/app.js points to the files missing from the workspace: [http://localhost/B2BMessageRunner/WebApp/build/scripts/bundle/c:\code\B2B.MessageRunner\MessageRunner.Web.Ux\WebApp\app\scripts\config\Config.js]
```

Note that the bundle/scripts/bundle directory is where my mapped JS file gets copied too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with the standard Chrome but it works on the last Chrome Canary.

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html